# Writing regular expression for complex validation

Tags: javascript

I have to validate a string which can

1. Start and end with numbers or letters.
2. must contain only lowercase letters, numbers, dashes `(-)`, underscores `(_)`, and dots.
3. must contain `3` to `63` characters. Names containing dots can contain up to `222` characters, but each dot-separated component can be no longer than`63` characters.
4. cannot be IP address
5. cannot start with prefix `"AABRA"`

I have written some expression but it only validates string beginning with alphabet and number, the string can only contain listed above special characters

```
^[a-z0-9][-_. a-z0-9]+[a-z0-9]$
```

But how can I validate string like `"abc.bys.123123"`, where the length of the word between `.` should be between 3 to 63

Comment: Is there an actual necessity to try and cram all this into a single regex? Is regex the only thing you have available in that environment, or can you do some extra JS coding as well?

Comment: {3,63} is between 3 and 63 characters, there is a similar expression to express up to 222 characters.

Comment: I don't understand how "names containing dots can contain up to 222 characters" and that the string "must contain 3 to 63 characters".

Comment: The total length of the string should not exceed 222 characters. String "aaaaaaaaaaaaaa.bbbbbbbbbbbbb.ccccccccccc", here length of substring aaa or bbb or ccc should be between 3 to 63, but overall the total length should be max of 222.

Comment: That's clearer. And can you answer @04FS's question? You can only use a regex pattern for some reasons or you can also use javascript?

Comment: @04FS: I can use regex only as it's for JSON validator

Answer (score 0):

Try the below regEx

**^([a-z\d]*[-_. a-z0-9]*([a-z\d]+)){3,63}$**

Tested the cases u mentioned

[Test Cases](https://regex101.com/r/r1rzHx/1)

Comment: "try this" is not a useful explanation of your solution.

Comment: the regex doesn't validate the length of substring between the dot(.) For example "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.bbbbbb_-bbbbbbbb.cccccccc". in this example, substring "aaaaa" can have more than 63 characters.

Answer (score 0):

For m to n repeatations, use {m, n}. So regex would be `^[a-z0-9][-_. a-z0-9]{3,63}[a-z0-9]$`

Edit: Not exactly what you are asking for. But this should help with the correct implementation.
To learn regex try this https://regexone.com/